# Storybook default export (non-named) in combination with template as opposed to component

Tags: angular, storybook

With storybook you can use a template in an export a named story by:

```
export default {
  title: 'My Component',
} as Meta;
export const Default: Story<any> = () => ({
  template: `
    <p>My story</p>
  `
});
```

And this shows up in the sidebar as:

- My Component

  - Default (<--- don't want this)

But since it's a one page thing, I don't want "Default" to show up in the second level, but just the first level as a link.

Now I've found [in the docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/introduction) that you can use the *default export* for such a thing:

```
// Button.stories.js

import React from 'react';
import { Button } from './Button';

export default {
  title: 'Components/Button',
  component: Button, // I don't have a component, just a template
}
```

However, that default export example makes use of "component" and it does not seem to have a "template" option.

Is there some way you can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is slightly late answer, but to make extra node to disappear from a sidebar you need your named export to match story's title. Like this:

```
export default {
  title: 'My Component',
};

export const MyComponent = () => (<p>My story</p>);
```

You can read more here:
https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/naming-components-and-hierarchy#single-story-hoisting

Comment: That's working for "Mycomponent" but not working for "MyComponent" — having a camelCase in component name is making unnecessary "MyComponent ↳ My Component" nesting, dunno why, also see the space in second part after "My" because of camelCase. Dunno what to do with it :(